# dropzone.js does not do the "action" param

Tags: javascript, php

I've been doing file uploads the conventional way for years and have a well tested server script for handling $_FILES[]. I came across dropzone by accident & it looked too good to be true.

Initially I used my well tested server side script and the simple form shown on the dropzone website. A thumbnail of the picture I had dropped on to the form appeared, plus tick.But nothing happened at the server. After hours of fiddling around, with jquery enabled or disabled and using IE11, latest Chrome. Firefox, Opera etc. I eventually made the very simplest upload target (server script) which simply echoes  'AAAGGGHHH' then quits, but that does not work either.

I'm led to the conclusion that the "action" parameter in the form tag is not being acted upon. But what could be simpler to code ? No one else has flagged this as a problem. I keep staring at these 3 lines of HTML hoping that I'll see the error.

BTW - if I put a submit button the form and click it, then I get to see AAAGGGHHH !

Here's the main file - a direct copy of the simple demo on the dropzone.js website

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/dropzone.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form class="dropzone" action="upload.php">

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the target for the post - the simplest possible POST target !

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: KT
 * Date: 27/07/2015
 * Time: 18:06
 */
 echo "WAAAAHHHOOOOOOOOO";
```

Comment: Please share some code with us or a fiddle. Do you honestly think that we can find the problem with your actual question?

Comment: Yes - if someone else had the same problem ( form not POSTing) and fixed it they would be able to tell me what they did